# Rendering template within context in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Is it possible to render a template, or even just a partial, from within the context passed to a top level template? It seems like this might require recursive rendering, but maybe I'm missing something.

The example below demonstrates this using Bootstrap.

Say this is my top level template:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{{description}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And my context is:

```
{
  description: "\
    Some text before the warning.\

    <div class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\">\
      <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</span>\
      My warning here.\
    </div>\

    Some text after the warning."
}
```

What I'd like to do is separate the alert into a partial for a number of reasons:

- Arbitrary placement within surrounding text
- Can make partials for types other than warning (danger, info, etc.)
- Can add as many as needed interspersed in the context string

For these reasons, it seems like it's not possible to put it into the top level template.

The partial would look something like this:

```
<script id="partial-warning-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
    {{{warning-message}}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Once this is in place, I would be able to use it like so:

```
{
  description: "\
    Some text before the warning.\

    {{> partial-warning-template \"My warning here.\"}}\

    Some text after the warning.\

    {{> partial-warning-template \"Now adding a second warning.\"}}"
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental - is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to include the partial blocks in the `description` value and expect them to be evaluated as partials by the top level template method; the entire `description` string will be spat out as a single literal string.

What you would need to do is to have the partials evaluated *before* you pass the context object with `description` to the top level template method.

If you have pre-compiled your partial in something like the following manner:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('warn', Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('partial-warning-template').innerHTML));
```

Then you will be able to call this partial when you construct your `description` string:

```
{
    description: 'Some text before the warning.' +
              Handlebars.partials.warn({ 'warning-message': 'My warning here.' }) +
              'Some text after the warning.' +
              Handlebars.partials.warn({ 'warning-message': 'Now adding a second warning.' })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For reference, I assigned the compiled template to a standard function, rather than pollute the partials object, but same effect.

    let warn = Handlebars.compile($("#partial-warning-template").html());

and later

    "Some text before the warning. " +
    warn("My Warning here.") +
    "Some text after the warning" +
    warn("Now adding a second warning.");

Where my template had {{{this}}} as the interior content.